# Excel, link 2 cells to have identical formatting

Tags: excel, formatting

In excel, I want to link 2 separate cells, in different worksheets to have exactly the same formatting. I also need the second cell to automatically update if the 1st cell is changed.

Is this possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: please check if my answer solves your issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using =sheetname!Cellref
so e.g if you need your cell to be the same as cell g4 in Prices you'd say =Prices!G4

Or, if that doesn't work, open both sheets, type = in the cell that is doing the copying and then flick to the other book and click the cell you wish it to copy =]

Comment: Thanks! This does copy the text in the cell - Is there a way to automatically copy things like the colour of the box also?

Comment: try going to the first worksheet, click the rectangle above the number 1 or first row (the rectangle is at the left of letter A that indicates column A) Copy, then select the cell in the second worksheet and then, Edit/Paste Special/Format OK.

Another way is using the button "copy format" instead of copy.

Comment: That rectangle selects the whole sheet, I'm only linking two cells to automatically update to have the same contents, although maybe I didnt read you reply properly.

Comment: Ah right, sorry, my bad, instead of clicking the rectangle, just click the first cell :) >.<

Comment: Thanks! does that link the two cells to automatically update the 2nd cell if the 1st one gets changed?

Comment: @Craig, I think user1619891 wants the colour of cell 2 to update as soon as the colour of cell 1 updates...

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA code will do the job.

Here you can check find an example:

https://github.com/thanosa/excel-vba-collection/tree/master/link_formatted_cells

You have to specify:

1. Source sheet name
2. Destination sheet name (it can be the same)
3. Source ID column
4. Source info column
5. Destination ID column
6. Destination info column

What it does is:

1. Reads the Destination ID from the Destination table
2. Looks-up the Destination ID in the source table to find the row
3. Copies the cell from the Source table based on row found above and the Source info column
4. Pastes the cell as-is in the Destination sheet on the current row and the destination info column.

> ```
> Const MAX_ROWS = 1000000
>
> Private Sub CopyFormatted()
>     ' Looks-up the destination id into the source look-up column to retrieve the row number
>     ' Then it copies the source cell into the destination cell
>     ' This is done to copy the format and the within cell new lines
>
>     ' Layout dependent for the Destination
>     dstWsName = "sheet1"
>     dstFirstRow = 2
>     dstIdCol = "A"
>     dstWriteCol = "B"
>
>     ' Layout dependent for the Source
>     srcWsName = "sheet1"
>     srcFirstRow = 2
>     srcLookupCol = "D"
>     srcReadCol = "E"
>
>     Call performancePre
>
>     Call lookUpCell(dstWsName, dstFirstRow, dstIdCol, dstWriteCol, _
>                     srcWsName, srcFirstRow, srcLookupCol, srcReadCol)
>
>     Call performancePost
>
> End Sub
>
>
> Private Sub lookUpCell(dstWsName, dstFirstRow, dstIdCol, dstWriteCol, _
>                        srcWsName, srcFirstRow, srcLookupCol, srcReadCol)
>     ' Reads a value in
>
>     Dim srcWs As Worksheet
>     Dim dstWs As Worksheet
>
>     Set srcWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(srcWsName)
>     Set dstWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(dstWsName)
>
>     Dim sourceIdsVector As Range
>     Set sourceIdsVector = srcWs.Range(srcLookupCol & srcFirstRow & ":" & srcLookupCol & MAX_ROWS)
>
>     ' Initialization
>     dstWriteRow = dstFirstRow
>     Do
>         srcRow = Empty
>         searchId = dstWs.Range(dstIdCol & dstWriteRow).Value
>
>         ' Make sure the id is not empty
>         If searchId = vbNullString Then Exit Do
>
>         ' Lookup the id to find the row number
>         For Each cell In sourceIdsVector.Cells
>             If cell.Value = "" Then Exit For
>
>             If cell.Value = searchId Then
>                 srcRow = cell.Row
>                 Exit For
>             End If
>         Next cell
>
>         ' If the search succeeds id does the copy paste of the cells.
>         If srcRow <> Empty Then
>
>             Dim srcCell As Range
>             Set srcCell = srcWs.Range(srcReadCol & srcRow)
>
>             Dim dstCell As Range
>             Set dstCell = dstWs.Range(dstWriteCol & dstWriteRow)
>
>             Call CopyPasteRange(srcWs, srcCell, dstWs, dstCell)
>
>         End If
>
>         ' Update
>         dstWriteRow = dstWriteRow + 1
>     Loop
>
> End Sub
>
>
> Private Sub CopyPasteRange(srcWs As Worksheet, srcRange As Range, dstWs As Worksheet, dstRange As Range)
>     ' Copy a ranges and pastes it to another
>     srcWs.Select
>     srcRange.Select
>     Selection.Copy
>
>     dstWs.Select
>     dstRange.Select
>     ActiveSheet.Paste
>
>     Application.CutCopyMode = False
>
> End Sub
>
>
> Private Sub performancePre()
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>     Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
>     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
>     Application.EnableEvents = False
>     ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False 'note this is a sheet-level setting
> End Sub
>
>
> Private Sub performancePost()
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
>     Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
>     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
>     Application.EnableEvents = True
>     ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True 'note this is a sheet-level setting
> End Sub
> ```